# Disabling EFS recovery domain policy on local account

Tags: windows-8, active-directory

I would like my personal home folder to be protected by EFS without my domain administrator having access.

I setup a separate local account so I can login with my personal microsoft account instead of the domain account.

In this local account, I've used EFS on my entire home folder.

However, when I right click the details, it says a recovery certificate is listed for administrator@domain, as defined by recovery policy.

How can I remove access so that I only myself with knowledge of my personal account password can view my files?

Comment: I don't think your IT department would be too thrilled with you trying to circumvent policy settings. Ask them. You can't override a GPO.

Comment: I don't think you can because the computer is controlled by a DCso certain rules may have been enforced for anyone using the computer, regardless of whether you are using a Microsoft account or local. Group Policy will always take precedence. A recovery agent (your DC) is doing its job and making sure YOU don't break your encrypted files. I would recommend you let your DC being a recovery agent. If you don't want people to access your files from work: keep them off your work computer. Store them on your OneDrive.

Comment: I understand, but it's still a valid question. Perhaps I have sensitive data that even the admin should not have access to. Would truecrypt be a suitable alternative?